# chrome.tabs is not present in chrome object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am adding this listener in background.js file which is a background script

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener( function(info) {
     chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, function(tab) { 
            chrome.tabs.reload(); 
     }); 
});
```

But in the chrome object tabs are not there.

The manifest file is

```
    {
      "name": "Tab Logger",
      "description": "Logs the clicked tabs with time",
      "version": "0.1",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "app": {
        "background": {
          "scripts": ["background.js"]
        }
      },
      "permissions": [
          "tabs"
        ],


"icons": { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.tabs` API is [not listed as supported](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index) for Apps, and your manifest is for an app and not an extension.

You will need to either make an extension, or not use `tabs` API.

---

To convert your manifest to an extension simply change

```
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
```

into

```
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
```